# How to create attributes to display icon in list page?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.4

Am using Magento 1.9.2.4. I want to display icons respective to the products in product list page (i.e. below the 'price'). So I created an attribute with label `Iconlist` like below,

[image]

and I added the attribute in `list.phtml` like

```
            <?php echo $_product->getIconlist(); ?>
```

But am not able to see any changes. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don need all that xml markup to add an attribute to the product grid. Just edit the attribute in the backend, set the field `Used in Product Listing` to `Yes`, reindex everything and you should be able to use in `catalog/product/list.phtml` this:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>
```

Comment: manufacturer is the attribute name.

Comment: how to exhibit an icon  in list page?

Comment: Is this `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>` the way to bring the content we enter in TextArea at list page?

Comment: For icon you have to add an attribute to images tab of your product.

Comment: Also check this link you will be getting all the details how to add an attribute and how to get that on the frontend.

http://sarathlal.com/create-and-use-custom-image-attribute-in-magento/

Answer (score 2):

You should select "Media Image"

[image]

Then after assigning this attribute to attribut set, you can see this attribute in "Images" tab.

[image]

Upload/Select Icon here and you can fetch this icon to Listing page

```
$p = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());
echo $p->getIconsunderPrice();
```

Comment: how to fetch this icon to list page?

Comment: In this way we can only add one image to list page.

Comment: Updated answer. For Multiple icons you should create MultiSelect attribute with options like `abc.png, def.png, etc...` (NAME of icon images, PRE-UPLOADED somewhere in media directory). Then in listing page you can use this attribute to generate image sources(SRC) for `<IMG />` tag

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getIconlist(), 'Iconlist');
```

This will do the translatation of `{{media .... }}`